# "An exception occured in driver : could not find driver" in Symfony 3.4 app

Tags: php, symfony, pdo

> An exception occured in driver : could not find driver.

Got this error since this morning and I've tried to reinstall the new version of PHP, of php-mysql, etc... but nothing happened.

[image]

Error on this line :

[image]

```
return new Exception/DriverException($message, $exception);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you restart apache or whatever you're using after installing?

Comment: @BrettGregson yes already done

Comment: @KoenHollander already tried all of this answers in the post

Comment: @pierreafranck You did'nt mention it in your post. Please be more clearly ;)

Comment: @KoenHollander ohw sorry ! i know it now :)

Comment: Show us your `doctrine:dbal` config too please.